# Issues with embedded Rust semihosting on windows

Tags: windows, rust, arm, embedded, qemu

I'm a low-level dev in training, trying to get into embedded Rust.
I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sYnzFe9A6E) great video on how to get started without hardware, and I jumped on it. I got qemu up and running, and my program builds perfectly, but when I try to run it, I get this error:

Timer with period zero, disabling

error: process didn't exit successfully: `qemu-system-arm -cpu cortex-m3 -machine lm3s6965evb -nographic -semihosting-config enable=on,target=native -kernel target\thumbv7m-none-eabi\debug\embeddedtest` (exit code: 0xc0000409, STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN)

I'm quite confused and didn't see this anywhere else, so I hope you can help me out

Comment: Is a minimal program with a main function and an empty loop working ? Could you include your program code to your original question ?

Comment: What is the version of `qemu` you are using ? execute `qemu-system-arm --version`,  you should get somethinh like: `QEMU emulator version 7.0.0 (v7.0.0-11902-g1d935f4a02-dirty)`
`Copyright (c) 2003-2022 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers`

Comment: I got the exact same result from running the version command. And no, the infinite loop does not run, it is that, that gives me the error